# React Native error : 'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, npx

I have been using React-Native for a project it's been more than a month, to create the app I uninstalled the react-native-cli and followed what is described in the official docs (https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). Yesterday, I modified an existing project (from github) and run :

- npm install
- npx react-native run-android

I had some errors so I updated npm, everything worked fine. I restarted my computer and tried to create a new app using the following command:

- npx react-native init Test

This is the error that I get:
[image: 'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command...]

I uninstalled Node and installed the newest version (16.0.0) with npm version (7.11.2) and npx version (7.11.2).

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: as I understand, you've used windows.. so may there you don't have set environment variable for "react-native" execution file path.. after uninstalling it was removed and not set again.. for more read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/react-native-for-android)

Comment: this seems to indicate there is a problem with `node_modules/.bin` symlink for react-native. a simple solution would be to delete node_modules and then `npm i` again. a fresh install should create the symlink for react-native at `node_modules/.bin/react-native` so it can be used from CLI as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling global packages
use this commond

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

then restart computer and try create new app

> I restarted my computer and tried to create a new app using the following command: npx react-native run-android Test

to create new app in react native use `init` not `run-android`

```
npx react-native init Test
```

Comment: I removed node and npm from the AppData/Roaming and installed node again. I followed after that your answer and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to install react native cli but first Add npm path to your Environment variables; both system and user then  install npm and react-native cli.
and if that does not work,Solution  is to install react-native-cli globally You can install it globally by using the below command:

`npm install -g react-native-cli`

Comment: "npm install -g react-native-cli" is not recommended by React Native doc

Comment: did you add the npm path to your env before installing?

Comment: it's done automatically when installing node.

Comment: ok its possible that your system or user environment PATH variable was edited, you can uninstall NodeJs and install it again or add below path to end of PATH variable into user variables the restart the Windows :

C:\Users[USER-NAME]\AppData\Roaming\npm

this should work.

Comment: I think it was a problem with npm versions, it messed up with the Path variable. I did this few minutes ago. Thank you!

Comment: glad i could help , please leave a vote review